# java - cannot find date using regex in this text

Tags: java, regex

I have a text which contains also this kind of dates: '`Date Reported26/09/2010 08:22`' and I want to extract the date with regex (because date is different in this taxes, so I am using this regex:

```
private static String PATTERN_DATE_REPORTED = "Date Reported[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}";
```

and do the extract like:

```
if ((value = extractWithRegEx(PATTERN_DATE_REPORTED, text)) != null) {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            try {
                metadata.setDateReported(df.parse(value));
                System.out.println("Succesfully converted report date: "+metadata.getDateReported().toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured when converting report date: "+ e.getMessage());
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Date Reported not found by this regex");
        }
```

where extractWithRegEx is defined like:

```
public String extractWithRegEx(String regextype, String input) {
    String matchedString = null;

    if (regextype != null && input != null) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regextype).matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            matchedString = matcher.group(0);
            if (matcher.groupCount() > 0) {
                matchedString = matcher.group(1);
            }
        }
    }
    return matchedString;
}
```

The issue: it does not find my date based on the above regex.

**I am very sure** the `extractWithRegEx` is correct because it works for other regex to find other type of text but for this date I think something is wrong in the rest of the code...Can you see the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were missing round brackets from the regular expression.

```
private static String PATTERN_DATE_REPORTED = "Date Reported([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this! I was pulling my hair out cause the expression should match, but you are correct. It will be hard to find any groups without round brackets in the regex.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if you feel it is correct. :) Hope your project goes well.

Comment: If I check my input with my regex on this site: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ it seems to work without round brackets...pretty strange...

Comment: @cristian-boariu It can match it, but there is nothing to extract from the expression, that is what you are getting.